# How to avoid request waterfalls with nested routes / query components using Apollo and React Router?

Tags: react-router, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

If I have some deeply nested routes containing a query component each, is there a way to combine those queries or run them in parallel using any routing solution with apollo client? Preferably react-router.

eg.

```
/parent/child/:id/something
```

The parent route would have a query and fetch some data, so would the child (with a specific id) and eventually a 3rd query might be in the "something" view to request additional data.

So when I go to `/parent/child/:id/something` directly, how can I get all the data without doing 3 graphql requests but only 1? If that is not possible, how to at least make the requests run in parallel, so I do not have to wait for the first, second and third?

To my big surprise have yet to find any info for Apollo client about this performance bottleneck and potential solutions to combat them.

I've looked into react-router-config for setting up static routes, but still not sure what logic to write in there to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Apollo doesn't support your usecase.
if you want to pack the 3 request into 1, Maybe the solution is create a new query in your graphQLServer and call 3 times into your backend services, and return all your expected data, so your client only need to call once instead of a few times. and all you do in client side will be passing props only

How you can run it in parallel if the second would need ID from first, and third need ID from second. this is impossible

---

Updated Answer: if all of these query, need an ID, you can do it like this i think. hope i don't got your questions wrong.

```
query bigQuery($id: String!){
   query1(id: $id) {
      field1
      field2
   }
   query2(id: $id) {
      field1
      field2
   }
   query3(id: $id) {
      field1
      field2
   }
}
```

Comment: "Data fetching" in parallel. ;-) You do know the id from the URL. I do believe i heard combining the queries or fetching in parallel would Indeed be possible with static routing such as react-router-config. But how is the question

Comment: oh, it's a new thing for me. does the `id` from the URL, used for these 3 request ? if one `ID` used for 3 request, you can simply join these 3 queries into 1 is it ? i've updated my answer.

Comment: /parent would not have an id. It's about having queries on each level that only fetches what is needed on that level.